# Correct way to connect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I've been told that having a username and password in the web.config file is not good practice (or safe) when wanting to connect to an `sql` server to get data for your `asp.net` page.

If that is the case, how exactly am I supposed to be connecting to the `sql` server?

Comment: If not using integrated security: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You can switch to integrated security where the account the application is running as is assumed to be a user within SQL Server. Or you can encrypt the connection strings in the configuration file.

Comment: @mason , if using integrated security for a 1000 user firm, does that mean all 1000 users need to be given rights to access the sql server for the integrated security approach to work?  Or can you force integrated security to use a specific account for all 1000 users?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, , if using integrated security for a 1000 user firm, does that mean all 1000 users need to be given rights to access the sql server for the integrated security approach to work?  Or can you force integrated security to use a specific account for all 1000 users?

Comment: Just the account that the application is running as, which is not the same as the logged in account (unless using passthrough authentication).

Comment: @mason, do you have a link on how to set up integrated security.  I've tried in the past and it tries to use the user logged in, as the user to access sql and gives a permission denied error, as the user does not have the appropriate permission on sql which he rightfully should not have.

Comment: You're as capable of using a search engine to find such instructions as I am.

Comment: Using Integrated Security assign rights to User Groups (not Users directly), that way you do not need to maintain permissions for 1000s of Users, just for x number of different groups

Comment: @JonathanWillcock , When I try to use integrated security, I get `Login failed for user 'domain_name_goes_here\server_name_goes_here$'.`  Does this mean I have to create the `server_name_goes_here` as a user on the sql server?

Comment: Or create a dedicated account, set your application pool to run as that account, and add the necessary permissions in SQL Server for that user.

Comment: use integrated security or encrypt the connection string

Comment: @oshirowanen No you just need to make sure that domainname\username is a member of a group that has permissions on the SQL Server